# Clean Syntax to Force Property to Have Value

Tags: msbuild

If you have a project reference with an empty path, it is an error, which is good:

```xml
<!-- ERROR -->
<ProjectReference Include="" />
```

But if you do the same thing with an empty property value, it is NOT an error.

```
<!-- No error or warning -->
<ProjectReference Include="$(ThisPropertyDoesNotExist)" />
```

Is there a way I can force the property to have a value?

I have tried using the MSBuild function `ValueOrDefault`. This kind of works but is a bit messy to use. It took a while to find something that would generate an error, but it seems like `'.'` and other numbers of dots works.

```
<!-- Build error when Property missing but messy -->
<ProjectReference Include="$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(Property)', '...'))" />
```

This does cause an error if the property has no value, but it is a bit messy.

I would also like to avoid referring to the property more than once if possible, since that can lead to mistakes. For example, I think I could assert that the property has a value by using an `Error` task with a `Condition` but then I have to refer to the property twice and I have to get the name exactly right for it to actually assert the property value correctly.

Ideally I could say something like these:

```
<ProjectReference Include="$(Property)" Required="true" />
```

```
<ProjectReference Include="$(Property.OrThrow())" />
```

Another option could be if there is some kind of `OptionStrict` feature I could enable that causes an error on any undefined property usage.

Comment: From within MSBuild 'code' there is not a distinction between a property that doesn't exist and a property with an empty value. Use the following to include `$(Property)` in the `ProjectReference` item collection when it is defined and has a value: `<ProjectReference Include="$(Property)" Condition="$(Property) != ''" />`

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild is (mostly) a declarative language. Unlike a procedural langauge, MSBuild doesn't have loops and it doesn't have unconditional branches.

Properties (and Items) are not the same as variables in a procedural language. There is no "declaration" of a property and MSBuild doesn't distinguish between a property that doesn't exist and a property with an empty value.

If you have a property that may not have a value, you can use a `Condition` attribute to test. In the following example, `$(Property)` will be included in `@(ProjectReference)` when it has a non-empty value.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="$(Property)" Condition="$(Property) != ''" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The [`Error` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/error-task?view=vs-2022) can be used within a target to create an error when `$(Property)` has no value.

```xml
  <Target Name="CheckProperty" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Error Text="'Property' has no value." Condition="$(Property) == ''" />
  </Target>
```

(For a warning see the [`Warning` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/warning-task?view=vs-2022).)

MSBuild processes a project in two phases: [evaluation and execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022). In the evaluation phase the "top level" elements which are not targets are evaluated and the order of targets is determined. In the execution phase the targets are "run".

An error or warning can't be generated during evaluation but the `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"` attribute sets the `CheckProperty` target to run very early in the target order. You could have one or multiple "error check" targets to ensure that important properties and items have values after the evaluation phase.

Comment: thanks, but the first example does nothing since the `ProjectReference` is not processed if the property is empty anyway. the point is to know if/when I use the wrong property name. how do I know the property name is right? The `Error` example I already know about, but it requires a separate property name use which still tells you nothing if you get the property name wrong in the `ProjectReference`. Possibly, if I could have some kind of "subroutine" that had both a `ProjectReference` and an `Error` that pulled from the one indicated property, that could work, but I don't think you can do that

Comment: my `ValueOrDefault` example does what I need already (cause an error if the property name is wrong), it's just messy and I'm not sure if I want to put it everywhere I have a project reference.

Comment: So, your concern is about catching a typo in the MSBuild XML file. Each use of the `ValueOrDefault` function will be invoked every time the project is run. You might instead consider running tests when the MSBuild file is changed.

Comment: typos yes, but also changing the name and making sure it is updated everywhere it is used. or an old file with an old name being used again and showing an error because of the old name. etc. (note that my solution has 300+ .csproj files.)

Comment: Hopefully you are able to use [`Import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022)s and [Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022) files to reduce duplication in the project files.

Comment: I have `Directory.Build.props` yes which is where I am organizing this further. previously I had relative paths in my project files but then it was very difficult to move them around without breaking them. So I have extracted the paths to `Directory.Build.props` which is so far infinitely better but I just wish that if I used a non-existent property name that that would be considered an error. I wonder if I could use `Import` to work as a `ProjectReference` and `Error` pair. Can I pass arguments to an `Import`?

Comment: An `Import` doesn't accept arguments. An `Import` is a textual include in the importing project. There are no subroutines in MSBuild. The `Directory.Build.props` is auto-imported very early before many of the 'standard' properties are defined. Unless you have a specific need to redefine something that early, avoid using the .props file and put everything into `Directory.Build.targets`. You can put `Import`s into the .targets file. One tactic would be to put related code, e.g. say there are two custom targets that share a custom property, in one file and then `Import` that file.

Comment: A tactic for paths: Is there a root folder with the .sln file for all the projects? You can use `<PropertyGroup><RootDir Condition="'$(RootDir)' == ''">$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove($(MSBuildProjectDirectory), 'Solution.sln'))</RootDir></PropertyGroup>` to find the root folder from the current project and define a property. (If the .sln file is not suitable you can create an arbitrary but uniquely named file to use to locate the root.) Regardless of how deep in the tree a project might be, `$(RootDir)/shared` will be the same path.